# Same entrypoint in windows docker produces different behavior in gitlab runner

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I created two Windows Docker images, one with Nvidia Cuda and one without. The images are based on `chocolatey/choco:v2.2.2-windows` and are build using a docker gitlab-runner on a Windows PC using the image `winamd64/docker:windowsservercore`.

The Dockerfiles are identical except for this one line:

`RUN choco install -y cuda`

The entrypoint definition in both docker files looks like this

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
COPY entrypoint.cmd entrypoint.cmd
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.cmd"]
```

entrypoint.cmd:

```
...
%*
```

When I use the two images in my gitlab pipeline, one runs the script and the other one doesn't. They both execute entrypoint.cmd, bot only the Cuda image runs the script from the gitlab pipeline.

Comment: Can you explain a little better  what you mean by "only the Cuda image runs the script from the gitlab pipeline"? Is it skipping only the script body, or the entire command the runner is supposed to execute from Gitlab side? Does your `entrypoint.cmd` by chance already cause an error?

Comment: Yes, it is skipping the entire script body. The `entrypoint.cmd` is identical in both images and I cannot see an error in gitlab. The job is marked as successful.